# Can I legally take my work's Visual Studio 2008 CD and install it at home?

Tags: visual-studio, licensing

I have been told that Microsoft allow employees of any company that uses it's products, such as Visual Studio 2008 or Office, to install them on their home machines.

Before I do so, is this correct?  It doesn't sound right to me, but I know microsoft have something called the "Home Use Program" but I'm not familiar with it and haven't seen VS2008 mentioned at all.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you CAN use Visual Studio at home. Check the licensing on page 16: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13350

Also, you may be able to use Office at home for personal use if your company's license is covered under HUP: http://hup.microsoft.com

Answer (score 4):

The [Home Use Program](http://hup.microsoft.com) is for office products not Visual Studio, unfortunately.

Dan

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not correct. There are no such regulations concerning developer products.

Comment: Actually you CAN use Visual Studio at home. Check the licensing on page 16: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13350